# gmaps4rails show hide functionality

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, gmaps4rails

I'm hoping to get a little bit of insight on show / hide functionality in gmaps4rails.

[example functionality](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_categories.html)

```
  // == shows all markers of a particular category, and ensures the checkbox is checked ==
  function show(category) {
    for (var i=0; i<gmarkers.length; i++) {
      if (gmarkers[i].mycategory == category) {
        gmarkers[i].setVisible(true);
      }
    }
    // == check the checkbox ==
    document.getElementById(category+"box").checked = true;
  }

  // == hides all markers of a particular category, and ensures the checkbox is cleared ==
  function hide(category) {
    for (var i=0; i<gmarkers.length; i++) {
      if (gmarkers[i].mycategory == category) {
        gmarkers[i].setVisible(false);
      }
    }
    // == clear the checkbox ==
    document.getElementById(category+"box").checked = false;
    // == close the info window, in case its open on a marker that we just hid
    infowindow.close();
  }

  // == a checkbox has been clicked ==
  function boxclick(box,category) {
    if (box.checked) {
      show(category);
    } else {
      hide(category);
    }
    // == rebuild the side bar
    makeSidebar();
  }

  function myclick(i) {
    google.maps.event.trigger(gmarkers[i],"click");
  }


  // == rebuilds the sidebar to match the markers currently displayed ==
  function makeSidebar() {
    var html = "";
    for (var i=0; i<gmarkers.length; i++) {
      if (gmarkers[i].getVisible()) {
        html += '<a href="javascript:myclick(' + i + ')">' + gmarkers[i].myname + '<\/a><br>';
      }
    }
    document.getElementById("side_bar").innerHTML = html;
  }
```

So, in my controller, I'm building a list of markers, and including their categories as json.

```
@markersLoc = @locSearch.to_gmaps4rails do |loc, marker|
  letter.next!
  marker_image = "http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=#{letter}|82ABDD|000000"
  marker.infowindow render_to_string(partial: '/events/info', 
                                     locals: {object: loc})
  marker.picture({picture: marker_image,
                  width: 32,
                  height: 32,
                  marker_anchor: [11,30],
                  shadow_picture: "http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_shadow",
                  shadow_width: 110,
                  shadow_height: 110,
                  shadow_anchor: [12,34]})
  marker.title loc.what
  marker.sidebar render_to_string(partial: '/events/sidebar', 
                                  locals: {object: loc, letter: marker_image})
  marker.json({cat: loc.category})
end
```

I'm kind of stuck, here.  I know the `:cat` string is available (ex: 1,3,4), but I'm not sure how to use it to achieve what I'm after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was able to pretty much use what was there, with some modification.  This gave me functionality to have 9 categories (could be more or less), and only view what I want.  Awesome.

```
// == shows all markers of a particular category, and ensures the checkbox is checked ==
function show(category) {
  var regEx = new RegExp("[" + category + "]")
  for (var i=0; i<Gmaps.map.markers.length; i++) {
    if (Gmaps.map.markers[i].cat) {
      if (Gmaps.map.markers[i].cat.match(regEx)) {
        Gmaps.map.showMarker(Gmaps.map.markers[i]);
      }
    }
  }
  // == check the checkbox ==
  document.getElementById(category+"box").checked = true;
}

// == hides all markers of a particular category, and ensures the checkbox is cleared ==
function hide(category) {
  var regEx = new RegExp("[" + category + "]")
  for (var i=0; i<Gmaps.map.markers.length; i++) {
    if (Gmaps.map.markers[i].cat) {
      if (Gmaps.map.markers[i].cat.match(regEx)) {
        Gmaps.map.hideMarker(Gmaps.map.markers[i]);
      }
    }
  }
  // == clear the checkbox ==
  document.getElementById(category+"box").checked = false;
  // == close the info window, in case its open on a marker that we just hid
  // Gmaps.map.infowindow.close();
}

// == a checkbox has been clicked ==
function boxclick(box,category) {
  if (box.checked) {
    show(category);
  } else {
    hide(category);
  }
}
```