# How to filter markers using gmaps4rails gem

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-maps, gmaps4rails

I am using gmaps4rails gem, rails 4.0.8, underscore.js and I can't seem to get the marker filter working correctly. It does filter, but only one category at a time (refreshes the whole map) and does not save the markers that were hidden.

My code is based on [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16179814/gmaps4rails-show-hide-functionality).

The code is posted below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
  handler.buildMap({ internal: {id: 'map'}}, function(){
    var markers_json = <%=raw @hash.to_json %>;
    var markers = handler.addMarkers(markers_json);
    handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
    handler.fitMapToBounds();
  });
});

// show markers 
function show(category) {

  handler.buildMap({ internal: {id: 'map'}}, function(){
  var markers_json = <%=raw @hash.to_json %>;
  var markers = _.map(markers_json, function(marker_json){
    var marker = handler.addMarker(marker_json);
    _.extend(marker, marker_json);
    return marker;
  });

  _.each(markers, function(marker, index){
    var pin = markers[index];
    if (pin.cat == category) {
      marker.show();
    } 
  });

  handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
  handler.fitMapToBounds();

});

// check the checkbox, using consulting for testing
document.getElementById(category+'box').checked = true;

}

// hide markers
function hide(category) {
// similar to show, except uses marker.hide(); 
}

function boxclick(box,category) {
  if (box.checked) {
    show(category);
  } else {
    hide(category);
  }
}
```

I'm not sure how to save the array of markers and when I try to buildMap after (so there aren't 3 instances of it) I end up breaking the map. I've been trying different ways to get the filter working but it is driving me crazy.

Any suggestions or direction would help. Thank you!

Comment: I made a working version here: http://plnkr.co/edit/Q5Nrolx6xKT9094M35mL?p=preview

Comment: Thank you apneadiving! It works perfectly. I love the gem and the support you provide, you are awesome.